# Changing FlowLayout Alignment after button click

Tags: java, swing, awt, flowlayout

I have a FlowLayout where default alignment of the component is CENTER. I want to change the component alignment (some Buttons) to left when the left button is clicked Like all the buttons will be skewed to left.

and this is my left button actionListener code

```
    left.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        }

    });
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: what is issue? Is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use revalidate() after changing layout.

```
left.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            revalidate();
        }

    });
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you can select this as answer.

Comment: I wanted to select it right away, but the system said, you can only select right answer after passing 5 min of the post.